# ZRAM vs ZSWAP for lower end hardware?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, ssd, performance

I spent the last 2 days researching about these two features that allow saving a bit of memory.
Here's how I understood them:

- ZRAM: Once the RAM reaches 100% usage (or the remaining
  incompressible memory), it'll
  compress some data and    put it in the ZRAM swap to lower the RAM
  usage. If the swap device runs out of space, then ZRAM Starts writing
  to the disk/SSD swap (if present).
- ZSWAP: Similarly to ZRAM, when the RAM usage reaches 100% (or again,
  when the RAM usage reaches the 'incompressible memory size' limit),
  the data starts being compressed and stored in the ZSWAMP pool and
  once that pool is full, the least recently used block gets written to
  the disk/SSD swap. If the block is not compressible, then the data
  gets written to the disk/SSD swap straight-away.

Did I get that right?

**1- Which one of these two uses more CPU?**

**2- Which is better for a device with low RAM?**

**3- Which is better for a device with an HDD? (since HDDs are so slow compared to SSDs)**

I have 8GB of RAM and a 1TB HDD with an i5-9400f CPU. I have trouble deciding because I have low RAM as well as a slow storage device instead of an SSD.

Comment: the title says ZRAM & SWAP, but the body says ZRAM & ZSWAP. So are you referring to swap or zswap?

Comment: That's my bad, in the title I meant ZRAM vs ZSWAP.

Answer (score 4):

> 1- Which one of these two uses more CPU?

Evidently ZRAM will try to compress everything, even incompressible data,
and keep it in the allocated compressed cache, so wasting RAM space and CPU.

> 2- Which is better for a device with low RAM?

ZSWAP is better under almost all conditions, as its RAM cache is dynamic,
shrinking or expanding as required. Thus memory management is done much
more efficiently.

> 3- Which is better for a device with an HDD? (since HDDs are so slow
> compared to SSDs)

ZSWAP, as it will make better use of the RAM.

Comment: The first point is wrong, zram consumes almost no RAM space when nothing is swapped in. The limit is the maximum uncompressed size, not the fixed compressed cache size. And zswap is worse because it isn't actively updated like zram

Comment: @phuclv I think harrymc is correct as far as I've read.

"zram consumes almost no RAM space when nothing is swapped in."

He didn't mean how much RAM either feature consumes, but rather he meant how efficient it is with memory usage and management. Unlike ZSWAP, what ZRAM does is it compresses and stores everything in the swap once the RAM gets filled up.
What ZSWAP does however, is it tries to compress data. If that data wasn't able to be compressed to a certain degree, ZSWAP sends it to the disk instead to save some RAM since keeping that incompressible data in the pool is pointless.

Comment: @alex keeping uncompressed stuff in memory is not pointless. It is still faster. Swapping it out is pointless in this case, but the kernel doesn't know so it will do so anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As harrymc stated in his answer, the RAM is used more efficiently in ZSWAP. However, the conclusion is not complete in my opinion. It is way too focused on this one little aspect. And I understand what he means, but this exact answer has led me into believing that ZSWAP was always better. And I experienced the opposite on my machine, after switching to Fedora Silverblue which uses ZRAM and should work worse under memory pressure. But it worked much much better, so I investigated a lot and would like to add my thoughts and also try to explain what might cause the differences.

As always, it depends what is better. The workload will make the difference.

The point that I want to add to his answer: ZSWAP will increase the IO load of your hard drive for incompressible data. It will not hold it in RAM at all, it will always write it to disc. And that can lead to a massive reduction of your applications performance, if it relies on a fast hard drive (high IO load).

This problem is really big with HDDs. For uses of HDDs I'd personally always default to ZRAM, not to ZSWAP.

But even on SSDs this can easily lead to better performance and especially latency. When looking at the performance benchmarks of any SSD, you will find that with random reads of 4k blocks they really don't perform that well; so if your NVME PCIE Gen5 SSD reads data at 80MB per second, that is way slower (about 100x) than what ZRAM will do on a modern CPU. How much this affects the real workload has to be tested, in my experience on a desktop ZRAM performed much better.

On the other hand, if there is much uncompressible data, ZRAM can't do anything useful with that; it will consume CPU time to (not) compress it and still leave you with too little RAM in the end.