# Would I gain performance from setting up my swap file to be at the beginning of the disk in Linux for gaming?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, performance, gaming

When installing Arch Linux, I have to set up 3 partitions - EFI system partition, swap and root. I've read numerous times that files at the start of the disk are read and written faster, so wouldn't setting up swap to be the first partition, followed by root then followed by EFI be better for gaming performance?

Comment: The difference will be marginal at best. It certainly isn't going to make a struggling or memory starved system suddenly usable. The two best options are replacing the hard disk with an SSD and installing more memory, out of preference it should be both those things.

Comment: Swap is not used if your system is not overflowing its memory.

Comment: I only have 8GB of RAM and that's not very sufficient for gaming. I will be upgrading soon though but for the time being I'm trying to do little optimizations.

Comment: Judging by your other posts [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1727160/zram-vs-zswap-for-lower-end-hardware) and [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1727285/what-are-the-effects-of-decreasing-or-increasing-swappiness-when-using-zswap-in) you have a system that you are trying to bandaid into being vaguely usable. It is not worth the effort. You will, at best, get a couple of percent improvement if you are lucky and at worst you are adding hurdles that you will one day need or want to undo to get rid of the "optimisations" needed for a low memory system.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and just deal with the system as it is until you can actually fix the problems.

Comment: hitting the swap for game files is a latency hit for "realtime" games. In addition, very many realtime 3D games do not rely on system RAM: they use VRAM (GPU) RAM. On my system, Doom Eternal, for example was peaking at about 2.5GB (but maxed the  VRAM). "Open world" games rely on more system ram because of trackable entities, but they typically don't need 6-8GB currently (but will happily fill Vram)